# Rails: Using group() on a joined table column without raw SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, merge, group

I have a small problem with grouping an ActiveRecord::Relation. I am trying to group a query by a joined table column without using raw SQL.

The code at the moment looks like that:

```
Sale::Product.joins(stock_product::supplier).group('core_suppliers.id').first
```

Result:

```
Sale::Product Load (42989.5ms)  SELECT  `sale_products`.* FROM `sale_products` INNER JOIN `stock_products` ON `stock_products`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `stock_products`.`id` = `sale_products`.`stock_product_id` INNER JOIN `core_suppliers` ON `core_suppliers`.`id` = `stock_products`.`core_supplier_id` GROUP BY core_suppliers.id ORDER BY `sale_products`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

I tried to solve this problem by using `merge`:

```
Sale::Product.joins(stock_product: :supplier).merge(::Core::Supplier.group(:id)).first
```

Result:

```
Sale::Product Load (32428.4ms)  SELECT  `sale_products`.* FROM `sale_products` INNER JOIN `stock_products` ON `stock_products`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `stock_products`.`id` = `sale_products`.`stock_product_id` INNER JOIN `core_suppliers` ON `core_suppliers`.`id` = `stock_products`.`core_supplier_id` GROUP BY `sale_products`.`core_supplier_id` ORDER BY `sale_products`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

I don't understand why Active::Record doesn't group my association by the column of the merged table. Especially since this way works with ```order()````.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I do not see an aggregate function so what is the intent behind the grouping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `Arel` library that was introduced in Rails 3 for use in constructing SQL queries.

Just replace `::Core::Supplier.group(core_supplier: :id)` to `::Core::Supplier.arel_table[:id]` in your code:

```rb
Sale::Product.joins(stock_product::supplier).group(::Core::Supplier.arel_table[:id]).first
```

**Update**

If you don't want to use **Arel** directly in your queries you can hide **Arel** implementation in ApplicationRecord like this:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.[](attribute)
    arel_table[attribute]
  end
end
```

And than your query can be rewritten like this:

```rb
Sale::Product.joins(stock_product::supplier).group(::Core::Supplier[:id]).first
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried your method and it works. But is there any way to solve this problem without using Raw SQL or Arel? In other words, is there no rails-like way.

Comment: Under the hood Rails ActiveRecord uses Arel to build queries, so this is Rails-like way)